# (PHP) Using the username of a logged in user to add it into another database

Tags: php, html, sql, bootstrap-4

So for my assignment, I need to use the username of a logged in user, and put that into another table in the same database, when the said user uploads an image, and whenever I try to upload, the database comes up with only the id, the rest is empty.

Processing Script:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['username'])) $username = $_POST['username'];    
if(isset($_POST['title'])) $title = $_POST['title'];
if(isset($_POST['category'])) $category = $_POST['category'];
if(isset($_POST['description'])) $description = $_POST['description'];
if(isset($_POST['tags'])) $tags = $_POST['tags'];

$filename = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$location = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

move_uploaded_file($location, "uploads/$filename");

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","", "artworks") or die(mysqli_error($db));
$q = "insert into artwork values(null, '$username', '$title', '$category', '$description', '$tags', '$filename')";
mysqli_query($db, $q) or die(mysqli_error($db));

header("Location:index.php");
exit(0); ?>
```

Login Script:

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['username'])) $username = $_POST['username'];
    if(isset($_POST['password'])) $password = $_POST['password'];

    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","", "artworks")  or die(mysqli_error($db));
    $q = "select * from member where username='$username' and password=SHA('$password')";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $q) or die(mysqli_error($db));

    if(mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0)
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header("Location:index.php");
        exit(0);
    }

    header("Location:register.php");?>
```

Upload Script

```
<?php
session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
    {
        header("Location:login.php");
        exit(0);
    }
?>

<?php include("header.inc");
        include("nav.inc"); ?>

<div class = "container">
<form role = "form-horizontal" method = "post" action = "add_ps.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div>
            <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "title" class="control-label col-xs-6">Title</label>
            <input type = "text" class = "form-control" id = "title" placeholder = "Title of Image">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "category" class="control-label col-xs-6">Category</label>
            <input type = "text" class = "form-control" id = "category" placeholder = "Category of Image">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "description" class="control-label col-xs-6">Description</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="description" placeholder = "Description of Image"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "tags" class="control-label col-xs-6">Tags (Seperate with comma)</label>
            <input type = "text" class = "form-control" id = "tag" placeholder = "Tag of Image">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "inputfile">File input</label>
            <input type = "file" id = "uploads">
            <p class = "help-block">Upload image here</p>
         </div>

        <div class = "form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
</div>

<?php include("footer.inc"); ?>
```

Hope this help, I feel like I am missing out on some tiny detail

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? What have you tried to debug it?

Comment: Have you tried including the column names in your SQL query? Like this: `INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);`

Comment: @rpm192 , i just tried it, and it came up with unknown column for the username table

Comment: Could you share the exact error?

Comment: Also in your form, you're missing the `name=""` attributes on every input.. This corresponds with the name of the variable in your `$_POST` array. For example: `name="myVar"` corresponds with `$_POST['myVar'];`

Comment: @rpm192 i just sorted the name part out. Just to test it out, I did an echo on my my index.php page as [echo "Welcome  $username"], and when I ran it, this error came up;
`Notice: Undefined variable: username in G:\xampp\htdocs\A3_Louis_Manabat\index.php on line 13
welcome`

Comment: You need to use `$_SESSION['username'];`, session variables can be accessed across multiple pages, whereas regular variables cannot. `echo "Welcome" . $_SESSION['username'];`

Comment: @rpm192 it still comes up as an undefined value

Comment: Did you start the session at the top of your `index.php` file?

Comment: @rpm192 just did. I tried doing that to my processing script `add_ps.php`, it still comes up as an empty value in the database

Comment: Try creating a file like [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/us6jCwuk), name it `auth.php` and include it in every page that requires login using `include('auth.php');`

Comment: already have that, and i use that for the `add.php` file, where the user needs to be logged in, in order to access that page

Comment: Include it in every page that you want to use `$_SESSION` variables in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have your fields in the form, your fields will be submitted with the `name=` value of the field which you don't have...

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Title of Image" name="title">
```

Repeat this for all of your fields.  I've also removed the spaces between the value and the attribute label.

Also when you submit the form, you check if a value is set and then set the variable you use, but you don't check if they aren't set and stop the form being submitted.  This means that if the field isn't set, the code will just continue with an empty value (as you've found)  it will also have some form of message(if you added reporting) to say the field doesn't exist...

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])) $username = $_POST['username'];    
if(isset($_POST['title'])) $title = $_POST['title'];
if(isset($_POST['category'])) $category = $_POST['category'];
if(isset($_POST['description'])) $description = $_POST['description'];
if(isset($_POST['tags'])) $tags = $_POST['tags'];
```

Would be better written to say if all the fields are set...

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['title']) ... ) { // Add rest of fields.
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    // Add rest of fields.

    // Process insert
}
```

Comment: I remembered this actually, I was told about this, I keep forgetting about it. Thank you! I just need to figure out the username part, and that is it

Answer (score 0):

Just add **name="image"** You are missing it

```
 <input type = "file" id = "uploads" name="image">
```

Comment: that worked, thank you, I missed that. But when I "SELECT * FROM ARTWORK;* it only comes up with the filename of the image I uploaded